# What's the antonym for 'word'?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the antonym for *word*? I first thought *silence*, but that doesn't quite fit; you can have written words. My next thought would be *illiterate*. So far I'm on the fence for that one too, because you can have speech. So, what is the antonym for *word*?

So far I've checked [a dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/word) (just gives synonyms) and [synonym-antonym finder](http://synonym-antonym.com/default.asp) that gives me *silence* (I explained why this didn't work above).

Comment: In the ghetto the antonym would be: false. =)

Comment: Hehe, or maybe grunt?

Comment: What is your context? Is this a Zen thing?

Comment: [Nonword](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/non-word)?

Comment: What's the antonym of *apple* or *sentence*? Unless you zero in on a specific idiom or meaning, this question has no meaning. Not every noun has an opposite.

Comment: Pretty much. A co-worker and I were bouncing around in a silly conversation and this made it to the forefront. Now we are both immensely curious on discovering a proper antonym for it.

Comment: @aedia λ Heh, I stand corrected. Off to write some non-sentence ramblings and find a nonapple to eat.

Comment: How about *gibberish*? It's as close as I can come up with, as in: "That page is full of words!" vs "That page is full of gibberish!". Here's a question: *Must* there be an antonym for everything?

Comment: @ghoppe orange is the antonym of apple

Comment: "Noise"? It carries the secondary implication of "signal to noise ratio".

Comment: I thought the opposite of "apple" was "IBM-compatible PC".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonword) says that *nonword* is a word. It's probably the closest thing you'll get to a suitable antonym for *word*.

Comment: Sorry Aedia, if you want to take credit for this, then by all means do so; I didn't see your comment beforehand.

Comment: Yep, the OED defines it as ‘A thing that is not a word; spec. an unrecorded or hitherto unused word; a word which has (or is regarded as having) no accepted meaning.’ The earliest of four citations is dated 1893.